# How to count the number of 'Mozilla' user agents in a log file in Linux

Tags: linux, file, logging, user-agent

Ok, so I can identify all the user agents from a log file using the command 
awk -F\" '{print $6}' but how can I expand on it and count how many of them are Mozilla user agents?

Thanks

Comment: `... | grep -c Mozilla` (where `...` is whatever command generates your list of user agents)

Answer (score 0):

To continue using `awk`, you can match for `Mozilla`, increment a counter, and then at the end, print the count, i.e.

```
  awk -F\" '$6~/Mozilla/{mozCnt++}END{print "Mozilla Count=" mozCnt}' files*
```

IHTH